# SharePoint csom ADAL Token 401 Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I generate a AAD Token that has the following rights.

```
AllSites.FullControl AllSites.Manage AllSites.Read 
AllSites.Write email Mail.Read Mail.Send MyFiles.Read 
MyFiles.Write openid profile Sites.Search.All TermStore.Read.All 
TermStore.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite.All
```

I am getting 401 Unauthorized when using nuget SharePointPnPCoreOnline, I also tried TTCUE.NEtCore.SharepointOnline.CSOM.

I have created an AAD App Registration with various permissions assigned.  The permissions are working for Mail.Read, just not SharePoint.

```
using (var context = new ClientContext("URL"))
        {
            context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Anonymous;
            context.FormDigestHandlingEnabled = false;
            context.ExecutingWebRequest +=
                delegate (object oSender, WebRequestEventArgs webRequestEventArgs)
                {
                    webRequestEventArgs.WebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] =
                        "Bearer " + token;
                };
            context.Load(context.Web);
            context.ExecuteQueryAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine(context.Web.Title);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer.  SharePoint CSOM access requires an Azure Active Directory V1 token.  Ensure you are not trying to access with a V2 token.